# Python - Automatically generate lists to stay under 100 song limit in spotify request

Tags: python, list, spotify, spotipy

I'm working on a little program using Spotipy to add the top 5 songs from every artist in a text file to a playlist. I like to listen to every band at a music festival and generating the playlist manually takes a LONG time.

So this seemed like a great solution! And it works great - except there is a 100 song limit per request. I have about 690 songs to add.

So basically, I could hard code 7 lists of 99 songs and then submit 7 requests using those lists (I think that will work right? splitting up the requests to get around the limit?) but I'd like the program to be able to work with more/less bands.

So is there a way to generate individual lists based on need? I'm new to python and programming in general (obviously). Or any other advice to accomplish this?

Thanks

```py
import pprint
import sys

import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util

tracks = []
lineupfile = open('lineup.txt','r')
lineup = [x.strip('\n') for x in lineupfile.readlines()]

numberofbands = len(lineup)
if(number)

if len(sys.argv) > 2:
    username = sys.argv[1]
    playlist_id = sys.argv[2]
else:
    print("Usage: %s username playlist_id ..." % (sys.argv[0],))
    sys.exit()

scope = 'playlist-modify-public'
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope, redirect_uri = 'https://example.com/callback/')

if token:
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
    sp.trace = False

    for x in range(0,len(lineup)):
        results = sp.search(q=str(lineup[x]), limit=5)
        for i, t in enumerate(results['tracks']['items']):
            tracks.append(str(t['id'].strip( 'u' )))
            print("adding ",t['id'],t['name'])
    results = sp.user_playlist_add_tracks(username, playlist_id, tracks, position=None)

else:
    print("Can't get token for", username)


print "Playlist Complete!"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
    results = sp.user_playlist_add_tracks(username, playlist_id, tracks, position=None)
```

To this:

```
while tracks:
    results = sp.user_playlist_add_tracks(username, playlist_id, tracks[:100], position=None)
    tracks = tracks[100:]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much